# Selecting records with unequal fields in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

These are the DDL&DML Queries

```
 CREATE TABLE SALES
    (
        S_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        S_DATE DATE,
        S_PRICE MONEY,
        CUSTOMER VARCHAR(30),
        P_ID INT
    );
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
    P_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    P_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    P_QUANTITY INT,
    P_TOTAL_SALE MONEY
);
--ADDING FOREIGN KEY TO THE SALES TABLE 
    ALTER TABLE SALES
    ADD FOREIGN KEY(P_ID)
    REFERENCES PRODUCT(P_ID);
```

And here is the SALES Table

| S_ID | S_DATE | S_PRICE | CUSTOMER | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008-11-12 | 1000.0000 | HANSEN | 1 |
| 2 | 2008-10-23 | 1600.0000 | NILSEN | 1 |
| 3 | 2008-09-02 | 700.0000 | HANSEN | 3 |
| 4 | 2008-09-03 | 300.0000 | HANSEN | 3 |
| 5 | 2008-08-30 | 2000.0000 | JENSEN | 4 |
| 6 | 2008-08-31 | 1500.0000 | JENSEN | 6 |

[image]

The PRODUCT table

| P_ID | P_NAME | P_QUANTITY | P_TOTAL_SALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SUPER | 100 | 2600.0000 |
| 2 | SALT | 100 | NULL |
| 3 | BISCUITS | 50 | 1000.0000 |
| 4 | TEA | 50 | 2000.0000 |
| 5 | BREAD | 10 | NULL |
| 6 | CAKE | 15 | NULL |
| 7 | TESLACAR | 5 | NULL |

[image]

I have written the following SQL query

```
--query 1
SELECT SP.P_ID, SP.TOTAL_PRICE, P.P_TOTAL_SALE
    FROM PRODUCT AS P
    INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT  P_ID, SUM(S_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE 
    FROM SALES
    GROUP BY P_ID) AS SP
    ON SP.P_ID = P.P_ID
```

That generates this output

[image: QUERY 1 PIC]

Now **I want to select the records where the TOTAL_PRICE and P_TOTAL_SALE mismatch i.e. record with P_ID = 6**

I have tried this

```
--query 2
    SELECT SP.P_ID, SP.TOTAL_PRICE, P.P_TOTAL_SALE
    FROM PRODUCT AS P
    INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT  P_ID, SUM(S_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE 
    FROM SALES
    GROUP BY P_ID) AS SP
    ON SP.P_ID = P.P_ID 
    WHERE SP.TOTAL_PRICE <> P.P_TOTAL_SALE;
```

That generates the following output

[image: QUERY2 PIC]

`WHERE NOT(SP.TOTAL_PRICE = P.P_TOTAL_SALE)`  also gives the same output.
This is not what I wanted. Don't you think it should give out the last record (with P_ID = 6)? Why not? I have also tried

```
WHERE SP.TOTAL_PRICE = P.P_TOTAL_SALE;
```

for the sake of clarity and I am getting this (which is what I expected):

[image]

Where am I lost(yes I am) and how can I solve it?

*Earlier I believe the outputs were quite opposite to the current outputs. I've restarted the SQL Server Management Studio (and also I am lost)*

**EDIT:**

It is actually working for not-null  values, I mean, `(not-null) <> (not-null)` is shown in the output but the `(not-null) <> (null)` is not shown in the output I should also get that record in the output.

So, one solution can be to insert 0 instead of NULL but remember this is money field so 0 as a value is not acceptable. What can be other solution? For which
`(not-null) <> (null)` is displayed in the output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For the sake of clarity, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags ,is it mysql or sql server? only tag your dbms

Comment: Your WHERE condition is comparing `p_id` to `p_id` which is going to match 100% of the time since it's your join condition (if they didn't match for a record in your result set, it wouldn't be a record in your result set to begin with) I think what you mean to do is `WHERE SP.TOTAL_PRICE <> P.P_TOTAL_SALE`